# Nested loop over all row-pairs in a Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe in the following format with ~80K rows.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Year': [1900, 1902, 1903], 'Name': ['Tom', 'Dick', 'Harry']})

   Year   Name
0  1900    Tom
1  1902   Dick
2  1903  Harry
```

I need to call a function with each combination of the name column as parameters. Currently I am doing this with the following code (substituting print for function call):

```
for i, n1 in enumerate(df.itertuples()):
    for n2 in df[i:].itertuples():
        print(n1.Name, n2.Name)
```

Is there a way to speed this up that I am missing?

PS: I need to keep track of the indices for each name pair. So if I run itertools.combinations on the index, then I still have to make costly df.loc calls.

Comment: Please provide the function code (or an example)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another solution to keep track of index/years would be to use a cross join:

```
import pandas as pd 

df = pd.DataFrame({'Year': [1900, 1902, 1903], 'Name': ['Tom', 'Dick', 'Harry']})
df = df.reset_index()
print(df.join(df, how='cross', lsuffix='_1', rsuffix='_2'))
```

Output:

```
   index_1  Year_1 Name_1  index_2  Year_2 Name_2
0        0    1900    Tom        0    1900    Tom
1        0    1900    Tom        1    1902   Dick
2        0    1900    Tom        2    1903  Harry
3        1    1902   Dick        0    1900    Tom
4        1    1902   Dick        1    1902   Dick
5        1    1902   Dick        2    1903  Harry
6        2    1903  Harry        0    1900    Tom
7        2    1903  Harry        1    1902   Dick
8        2    1903  Harry        2    1903  Harry
```

Comment: You have too many combinations

Comment: @Corralien Do you mean I'd run out of memory with 80k rows crossjoined?

Comment: From your code need `combinations_with_replacement`  output?

Comment: @primelens. Try it. I don't know your memory capacity

Comment: @Corralien and @jezrael you are both right. From OP original code it seems that only the first combination should be kept (dropping Dick/Tom because it comes after Tom/Dick). However that might be something to be handled by OP's function...   If not itertools is still an option after `reset_index`...

Answer (score 3):

You can use `itertools.combinations`:

```
import pandas as pd 
from itertools import combinations

df = pd.DataFrame({'Year': [1900, 1902, 1903], 'Name': ['Tom', 'Dick', 'Harry']})

for c in combinations(df['Name'], 2):
    print(c)
```

Output:

```
('Tom', 'Dick')
('Tom', 'Harry')
('Dick', 'Harry')
```

Or if you need replacement (Edit: keeping track of index):

```
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement
for (i1, n1), (i2, n2) in combinations_with_replacement(df.reset_index()[['index', 'Name']].values, 2):
    print(f"{i1}: {n1}, {i2}: {n2}")
```

Output:

```
0: Tom, 0: Tom
0: Tom, 1: Dick
0: Tom, 2: Harry
1: Dick, 1: Dick
1: Dick, 2: Harry
2: Harry, 2: Harry
```

Comment: Thanks. I've tried this, but unfortunately I have to keep track of the indices where my name pairs come from. Any way to do that?

Comment: You could use a cross join. See my other answer

Comment: I've edited this one to keep track of index too.

Comment: @Tranbi. Your answer gives me an idea :-) https://stackoverflow.com/a/75602247/15239951

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
out = (df.reset_index().merge(df.reset_index(), how='cross')
         .query('index_x <= index_y'))
print(out)

# Output
   index_x  Year_x Name_x  index_y  Year_y Name_y
0        0    1900    Tom        0    1900    Tom
1        0    1900    Tom        1    1902   Dick
2        0    1900    Tom        2    1903  Harry
4        1    1902   Dick        1    1902   Dick
5        1    1902   Dick        2    1903  Harry
8        2    1903  Harry        2    1903  Harry
```

Comment: Shouldn't `.query('index_x <= index_y')` be enough? Or is your query faster?

Answer (score 2):

If need pandas solution for ouput like `combinations_with_replacement` is possible use cross join and then filter necessary rows by mask:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Year': [1900, 1902, 1903], 'Name': ['Tom', 'Dick', 'Harry']})

mask = np.ravel(np.triu(np.ones((len(df),len(df)), dtype=bool)))
df1 = df.reset_index()
out = df1.merge(df1, how='cross')[mask]
print(out)
   index_x  Year_x Name_x  index_y  Year_y Name_y
0        0    1900    Tom        0    1900    Tom
1        0    1900    Tom        1    1902   Dick
2        0    1900    Tom        2    1903  Harry
4        1    1902   Dick        1    1902   Dick
5        1    1902   Dick        2    1903  Harry
8        2    1903  Harry        2    1903  Harry
```

Solution working well for any indices:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Year': [1900, 1902, 1903], 
                   'Name': ['Tom', 'Dick', 'Harry']}, 
                   index=list('abc'))
print(df)
   Year   Name
a  1900    Tom
b  1902   Dick
c  1903  Harry

mask = np.ravel(np.triu(np.ones((3,3), dtype=bool)))
df1 = df.reset_index()
df = df1.merge(df1, how='cross')[mask]
print(df)
  index_x  Year_x Name_x index_y  Year_y Name_y
0       a    1900    Tom       a    1900    Tom
1       a    1900    Tom       b    1902   Dick
2       a    1900    Tom       c    1903  Harry
4       b    1902   Dick       b    1902   Dick
5       b    1902   Dick       c    1903  Harry
8       c    1903  Harry       c    1903  Harry
```

Comment: Interesting approach with `np.triu` (someone seems to have algebra background ;-)) it would be interesting to time all solutions here. My guess is that `itertools` should come on top but my gut feeling has often been wrong about timings... Might do this in the evening...

Answer (score 1):

Another way with low memory footprint (avoid to generate all combinations then drop them) inspired by @Tranbi and `combinations_with_replacement`:

```
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement

# Enhanced by @mozway
a, b = map(list, zip(*combinations_with_replacement(df.index, 2)))
out = pd.concat([df.loc[a].reset_index(), 
                 df.loc[b].reset_index().add_suffix('2')],
                axis=1)
print(out)

# Output
   index  Year   Name  index2  Year2  Name2
0      0  1900    Tom       0   1900    Tom
1      0  1900    Tom       1   1902   Dick
2      0  1900    Tom       2   1903  Harry
3      1  1902   Dick       1   1902   Dick
4      1  1902   Dick       2   1903  Harry
5      2  1903  Harry       2   1903  Harry
```

Comment: Haha this is so convoluted! I love it! Someone has to do a benchmark of all solutions here :-D I might look into it this evening if noone does it until then ;-)

Comment: I'm too lazy for that :-) but the benchmark checks only speed not memory. I think my first answer and jezrael's answer will crash because the merge will consume all memory.

Comment: `timeit` will measure speed but [memory-profiler](https://pypi.org/project/memory-profiler/) should be able to assess memory consumption (never tried it though)

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution, based on [`numpy.broadcast_arrays`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.broadcast_arrays.html):

```
b = a = df['Name'].values.astype(str)
i1 = i2 = df.index.values

a, b, i1, i2 = a[:, None], b[None, :], i1[:, None], i2[None, :]

indexes = np.stack(np.broadcast_arrays(i1, i2), axis=-1).reshape(-1,2)
names = np.stack(np.broadcast_arrays(a, b), axis=-1).reshape(-1,2)

_, idx = np.unique(indexes, return_index=True, axis=0)
indexesu = indexes[idx, :]
namesu = names[idx, :]
m = indexesu[:,0] <= indexesu[:,1]

result = np.hstack([indexesu[m, :], namesu[m, :]])
out = pd.DataFrame(result, columns=['i1', 'i2', 'Name1', 'Name2'])
out = out.assign(**out[['i1', 'i2']].astype(int))
```

Output:

```
   i1  i2  Name1  Name2
0   0   0    Tom    Tom
1   0   1    Tom   Dick
2   0   2    Tom  Harry
3   1   1   Dick   Dick
4   1   2   Dick  Harry
5   2   2  Harry  Harry
```

Comment: The problem with that is you can't mix dtype so the integer index is transform as string. 0 -> '0', 1 -> '1', ...

Comment: Thanks, @Corralien, for commenting my answer. You are right, but I am now going to create a dataframe with the result numpy array and then the indexes will be numeric.